# In terms of sales, how popular was Sword Art Online II?

Tags: sword-art-online

A pretty straight forward question, what were the sales and/or projected sales of Sword Art Online season two?  How popular was it compared to season one, which was really popular?

Comment: maybe we can count on BD sales, but BD not come out just yet.

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa Well, the first two volumes are already on sale. OP might like to compare [Sword Art Online](http://www.someanithing.com/383) and [Sword Art Online II](http://www.someanithing.com/1059). As is virtually always the case with sequels, season 2 is selling less than season 1 so far, and that is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Newtype* magazine, *Sword Art Online II Volume I Blu-Ray DVD* sales ranks 5th in the charts. Volume II sales are still ongoing. In total and as of this post, the average sales ranks 4th when compared to other anime DVDs/BDs sales with a total of about 20,000 sales.

Source for Newtype (bottom-middle column): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYRUq.jpg

Average sales: https://web.archive.org/web/20140825012552/http://www.someanithing.com/1045